# Prestashop 1.6 custom module how to add custom input and table in Configuration at Back Office

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to create a custom footer module for my site, It is my first time to create a module in prestashop 1.6 and I read about this article

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Adding+a+configuration+page

my problem is i cannot fully understand if I need to create a custom table for my module or not

```
Configuration::updateValue('FOOTERCUSTOM_NAME', $footercustom);
```

as you can see in this code, the Configuration table is already created and `Configuration::updateValue` is a default prestashop code

if I wanted to create a  input 1 , input 2 and input 3 at our configuration page in module backoffice and it automatically output the data in the database at my `hookfooter`.
*what is the proper way of doing this?*

Note that I already succeeded in creating a basic module, my main problem in how to insert data on my database using the configuration in my module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to a create a custom table. With the `Configuration::updateValue` method you can store/update values in the `ps_configuration` table and you can retrieve these values with the `Configuration::get` and `Configuration::getMultiple` methods. Values can be removed with the `Configuration::deleteByName` method.

Example:

```
Configuration::updateValue('FOOTERCUSTOM_INPUT_1', $input1Stored);
$input1Retrieved = Configuration::get('FOOTERCUSTOM_INPUT_1');
```

Comment: what if i have many input, for example i have two module that puts their data in ps_configuration.then the ps_configuration will be overloaded. is it better to create a table for my module itself?

Comment: @AljonNgo I think that as long as you store only a couple of values per module it isn't worth to create a custom table, but if you want to store a lot of data or you want to store a more complex data structure then it  would be a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this guide as well, still valid

[http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-ThegetContent()method](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-ThegetContent%28%29method)